# php/xpath: Getting the content in nested divs

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following html code:

```
<div class='class1'> Content 1
<div class='class2'> Content 2
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to use xpath to only get the content between 'class1' and 'class2', aka just 'Content 1' by itself. This is what I have so far:

```
$classname = 'class1';
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
echo $results->item($x)->nodeValue;
```

But its returning back

```
Content 1 Content 2
```

Anyway to just get 'Content 1' by itself? Thanks!

Comment: Put `class` instead of `calss`

Comment: oops sorry that was a typo. sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know exactly what is going wrong with your code because we don't know what `$x` represents. The XPath you have is correct, but from you code I can't tell how you are printing your output. Below is a working example of what I think you are trying to achieve:

**PHP**

```
<?php

$string = 
<<<XML
    <div class='class1'> Content 1
        <div class='class2'> Content 2
        </div>
    </div>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$results = $xml->xpath('//div[@class="class1"]');
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result;
} 

?>
```

**Output**

```
Content 1
```

This creates a 'simple xml element' and then uses the XPath `//div[@class="class1"]` to look for your desired element. The `$results` variable returned is an array (which only holds one element), so I loop over it to print the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! It works. $x was part of a for loop I was doing, I forgot to replace it with 0 when I asked this question. Thanks mate!